# Django get count of foreign key records by grouping on source

Tags: django

I have two models,

Media:

```
class Media(models.Model):
    persons = models.ManyToManyField(
        Person,
        blank=True,
        related_name="media",
        help_text="Persons identified in the media",
    )

    reviews = GenericRelation(Review, related_query_name="media")

    source = models.ForeignKey(
        Source,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name="media",
        help_text="Source for this media",
    )
```

Review:

```
class Review(models.Model):
    """Represents a review made by an Account on an object
    """
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    review_item = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    reviewer = models.ForeignKey(
        Account,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        help_text="Account of the reviewer",
    )
```

I need to group `Media` based on `source` and get count of `source` where there is no review exists. In other words I need count of each `source` with where there is no relation with `reviews` exists.

Please advise.

Comment: `Review` has a GenericForeignKey which could point directly to a `Source`. Do you just want a count of `Source` where all related `Media` have no `Review`?

Comment: I need count of `Media` group by `Source` where there is no `Review` associated.

Source_1 -> Media Count 150

Which means `Source_1` has 150 `Media` where there are no reviews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will get you all `Source` objects annotated with a count of `Media` that has no related `Review`

```
from django.db.models import Count

Source.objects.filter(
    media__reviews__isnull=True
).annotate(
    Count('media')
).values()
```